# Matrioshka brains with stellar engines?

Tags: engineering, megastructures

I was originally writing a question about the safest location or arrangement for a Matrioshka brain network when I realised the problem could solved with a Matrioshka brain/stellar engine combination to keep the network of stars as dense as possible so information is sent over the shortest distances and also keep the network safe from collisions.

Rather than a Shkadov thruster design that requires a large reflective area and volume of reflected light which would disrupt or make it impossible for Matrioshka shells, they could have an array of Caplan thrusters which surround the star, which would hopefully allow an almost full sphere of Matrioshka shells and a single thruster or combination of a few thrusters could move the star in any direction, allowing the whole network of stars to adjust their positions when needed.

Is this something that could work? Would the Caplan thrusters (or other stellar engines if there are better options) disrupt the Matrioska brains? Would the engines be powerful enough to adjust the stars on short time-scales compared to the gravitation forces which could disrupt them?

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your question directly, you may gain some insight if you look up; Niven and Edward M. Lerner's Fleet of Worlds. The  [Puppeteer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierson%27s_Puppeteers) race have moved their worlds around their solar system for economic reasons, and finely begun moving the solar system for other reasons. To do so they arranged the planets into a  [Klemperer rosette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klemperer_rosette).
The drive is more or less hand waved away in the books but the method is adequately explained, and more thoroughly in surrounding literature.